How to upload barcode image in Codeigniter 3?
I am trying to use Zend library to upload barcode image, but everytime it's showing 500 internal server error. Don't know why this is repeatedly showing 500 internal server error? Anyone can help please?
Here is the code that I used in my controller.
$this->load->library('zend');
$this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');

Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'image', array('text' => 'Test'), array());

The above line (Zend_Barcode....) line is always shoowing 500 internal server error.
This is the image of the library folder
This is the image of the folder inside Zend folder

The Barcode class you're trying to use seems to be in the Zend\Barcode namespace, so I think you may need to add another 'Barcode' to both lines?
$this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode/Barcode');
Zend_Barcode_Barcode::factory('code128', 'image', array('text' => 'Test'), array());

No, still it is not working
